# "threadgroup_barrier" makes no difference

Tags: multithreading, gpu, metal, compute-shader, threadgroup

Currently I'm working with Metal compute shaders and trying to understand how GPU threads synchronization works there.

I wrote a simple code but it doesn't work the way I expect it:

Consider I have `threadgroup` variable, which is array where all threads can produce an output simultaneously.

```
    kernel void compute_features(device float output [[ buffer(0) ]],
                                 ushort2 group_pos [[ threadgroup_position_in_grid ]],
                                 ushort2 thread_pos [[ thread_position_in_threadgroup]],
                                 ushort tid [[ thread_index_in_threadgroup ]])
    {     
        threadgroup short blockIndices[288];

        float someValue = 0.0
        // doing some work here which fills someValue...

        blockIndices[thread_pos.y * THREAD_COUNT_X + thread_pos.x] = someValue;

        //wait when all threads are done with calculations
        threadgroup_barrier(mem_flags::mem_none);  
        output += blockIndices[thread_pos.y * THREAD_COUNT_X + thread_pos.x]; // filling out output variable with threads calculations
    }
```

The code above  doesn't work. Output variable doesn't contain all threads calculations, it contains only the value from the thread which was presumable the last at adding up a value to `output`. To me it seems like `threadgroup_barrier` does absolutely nothing.

Now, the interesting part. The code below works:

```
blockIndices[thread_pos.y * THREAD_COUNT_X + thread_pos.x] = someValue;

threadgroup_barrier(mem_flags::mem_none);  //wait when all threads are done with calculations
if (tid == 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 288; i ++) {
        output += blockIndices[i]; // filling out output variable with threads calculations
    }
}
```

And this code also works as good as the previous one:

```
blockIndices[thread_pos.y * THREAD_COUNT_X + thread_pos.x] = someValue;

if (tid == 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 288; i ++) {
        output += blockIndices[i]; // filling out output variable with threads calculations
    }
}
```

To summarize: My code works as expected only when I'm handling threadgroup memory in one GPU thread, no matter what's the id of it, it can be the last thread in the threadgroup as well as the first one. And presense of `threadgroup_barrier` makes absolutely no difference. I also used `threadgroup_barrier` with `mem_threadgroup` flag, code still doesn't work.

I understand that I might be missing some very important detail and I would be happy if someone can point me out to my errors. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write `output += blockIndices[...]`, all threads will try to perform this operation at the same time. But since `output` is not an atomic variable, this results in race conditions. It's not a threadsafe operation.

Your second solution is the correct one. You need to have just a single thread to collect the results (although you could split this up across multiple threads too). That it still works OK if you remove the barrier may just be due to luck.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Your answer makes a complete sense to me, thank you for cleaning mess in my head. Btw, I tried to split data saving to 2 threads, it seems that it works. But if I try to go above that, I'm starting to have some random problems.

Comment: A typical solution is to have 288/2 = 144 threads that each sum up two values. Then you add a threadgroup barrier. Next, you use 144/2 = 72 threads that each sum up two values. Follow that by a threadgroup barrier, next you have 72/2 = 36 threads. And so on. This is more efficient than having 1 thread doing all the summing up, but you do need to make sure there are barriers everywhere.